# Scraping text from a multiple URLs (dynamically generated) to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a Google spreadsheet that will scrape a career website's text for audit purposes but the problem is the URLs can increase or decrease each week and after a certain point in the URL address, the rest are dynamically generated.

I've used the likes of IMPORTXML previously but I'm having a problem with it scraping multiple websites that are dynamically generated.

So the website address is something like this Website.com/jobdetails/ajid/(Dynamically generated details).html. There can be anywhere between 30 - 50 webpages at any one time and I'm trying to find out if there's a way that I can scrape all the data in one section of the page into a spreadsheet. Ideally if I can do it across different cells that would be great, but if not that's fine too as long as I can copy and paste it from the spreadsheet to a word doc.

I hope this makes sense and thank you in advance for your time and help.

Currently I am able to get the data if I put in the exact website address and each paragraph goes on a new cell horizontally. Would be great if I could get this to go vertically down rather than horizontally across for each

.